# How can I make the search for find short in the object contained within the object?

Tags: javascript

The following function returns the object it finds using the find method on the object inside the object. But I think it's a very long road. Can I write shorter?

Thank you for your help

```js
let customers = [
  {
    active: true,
    id: 1,
    products: {
      householdProducts: [
        {productId: 5, name: "food processor"},
        {productId: 6, name: "mop"},
      ],
      carProducts: [
        {productId: 3, name: "headlight"},
        {productId: 4, name: "wiper"},
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    active: true,
    id: 2,
    products: {
      householdProducts: [
        {productId: 1, name: "cabinet"},
        {productId: 2, name: "lamp"},
      ],
      carProducts: [
        {productId: 7, name: "horn"},
        {productId: 8, name: "handbrake"},
      ],
    },
  },
];

let whichProducts = "householdProducts";

function checkInCustomer(id, name) {
  let result = undefined;

  for (let i = 0; i < customers.length; i++) {
    result = customers[i]["products"][whichProducts].find((product) => product?.productId === id && product?.name === name);
    if (result !== undefined) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(checkInCustomer(3, "headlight"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your outer `for` loop can be replaced with a call to [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), and your inner `.find()` method can become a call to [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). The `.some()` method will returns `true` once it finds a match based on the callback function you supply it with, otherwise, it will return `false`. In the below `.some()` function call, I've used [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to grab the properties `productId` and `name` which are then compared with the function arguments. I've also removed the dependencies your function has on global scope data, and instead passed those through as arguments to allow your function to behave standalone.

See example below:

```js
const customers = [ { active: true, id: 1, products: { householdProducts: [ {productId: 5, name: "food processor"}, {productId: 6, name: "mop"}, ], carProducts: [ {productId: 3, name: "headlight"}, {productId: 4, name: "wiper"}, ], }, }, { active: true, id: 2, products: { householdProducts: [ {productId: 1, name: "cabinet"}, {productId: 2, name: "lamp"}, ], carProducts: [ {productId: 7, name: "horn"}, {productId: 8, name: "handbrake"}, ], }, }, ];

function checkInCustomer(data, sId, sName, whichProducts = "householdProducts") {
  return data.find(customer =>
    customer.products[whichProducts].some(({productId, name}) => productId === sId && name === sName)
  );
}

console.log(checkInCustomer(customers, 6, "mop"));
```